# Accept Rails model attribute only if it was previously blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid, activemodel

I have a Rails model (persisted with Mongoid) that can be collaboratively edited by any registered user. However, I want to allow editing any particular attribute only if it was previously blank or nil.

For example, say someone created an object, and set its `title` attribute to `"Test Product"`. Then another user comes along and wants to add a value for `price`, which until now has been `nil`.

What's the best way to do this, while locking an attribute that has previously been entered?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [`ActiveRecord::Dirty`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) module for some nice utility methods you can use to do something like this:

```
NON_UPDATABLE_ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :title, :price]
before_validation :check_for_previously_set_attributes

private
def check_for_previously_set_attributes
  NON_UPDATABLE_ATTRIBUTES.each do |att|
    att = att.to_s
    # changes[att] will be an array of [prev_value, new_value] if the attribute has been changed
    errors.add(att, "cannot be updated because it has previously been set") if changes[att] && changes[att].first.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, i think, is by checking for it in the form itself.
Just say add :disabled => true to the input field if the person cannot edit it.

```
<% if @my_object.name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled => true %>
<% else %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled => true %>
<% end %>
```

(i think there is a prettier way to write this code)

But by using this the user has a visual feed back that he can't do something, it is always better to not allor something than to give an error message

Comment: You still need model validations so users can't just modify the form field and submit it anyways.

Comment: good point :) So i would go fo a combination of gareth and mine posts